# Why does Iron Man have to be flown to the gig?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, iron-man-2

In the post-credits opening of Iron Man 2, we see Tony Stark jump out of what appears to be a C-130 transport aircraft to air drop into the keynote address of the Stark Expo. Now, my question is: **why did he have to be flown in**? It seems to be vastly cheaper and more easily timed to just have him take to the air away from the venue using just the suit. I'm not sure the audience even realized that he just did a variation of a HALO jump so even flying in through the roof would have accomplished the same effect.

Is it just for Rule of Cool? It does look pretty amazing when you don't think about it too hard, which I guess goes for most of the movie, but I'm struggling to think of a reason, in-universe or not, for flying him in.

*As I recall, a trailer had Pepper Potts in the plane with him, but I would imagine them typically preferring their private plane over the sparse interior of a Hercules.*

Comment: Maybe he was lazy. Why fly in, when you can sit normally in an airplane, suit up and just jump.

Answer (score 16):

As Richard already [said](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113254/42419) he was terribly sick. There is also a deleted scene on the DVD showing Tony vomiting in the toilet of the plane. In fact, he did not want to go the Expo at all.

Comment: Good find. You have my +1

Answer (score 11):

This is covered in the film's [official tie-in graphic novelisation](http://marvel.com/comics/series/16670/marvels_iron_man_2_adaptation_2012).

**He was feeling sick**

[image]